# How to recreate or reset cached Observable, used with Retrofit to get new data?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

**I have:**

API, that returns list of data in `JSON`.

**My goal:**

Get this data via `Retrofit`+`RxJava`.

**My problem:**

I need only one network request and I do not want to start new one if screen was rotated before it finished. Also I need ability to refresh data from API.

**How I solve it:**

First was solved via Singlton and caching data in `Observable` with `cache()`.

Second - with totally recreating of `Retrofit` object (1), instance of retrofit-interface (2) and `Observable`(3) itself. I try to do only 3, but failed - `Observable` wasn't reseted and emits old, cached data.

**Question:**

My working way of recreating `Observable` looks bad. What is the proper/better way to recreate cached `Observable`?

---

There is my Singlton to get/recreate `Observalbe`:

```
public class SingltonRetrofit
{
    private static RxJavaCallAdapterFactory rxAdapter = RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io());

    private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    private static Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Const.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(rxAdapter)
            .build();

    private static GetModels apiService = retrofit.create(GetModels.class);
    private static Observable<ArrayList<Model>> observableModelsList;

    public static void reset()
    {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Const.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(rxAdapter)
                .build();
        apiService = retrofit.create(GetModels.class);
        observableModelsList = null;
    }

    public static Observable<ArrayList<Model>> getModelsObservable()
    {
        if (observableModelsList == null)
        {
            observableModelsList = apiService.getModelsList().cache();
        }
        return observableModelsList;
    }
}
```

**P.S.**

Same question in russian: [Как правильно пересоздать закэшированный Observable используемый вместе с Retrofit?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/541099/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solve it so:

I create `BehaviorSubject` in singlton. It receives `onError` or `onNext` from `Observable`, which created by `Retrofit`. Fragment subscribes to `BehaviorSubject` and receives its last event with data or error. When I need to refresh data, I recreate `BehaviorSubject`, re-subscribe to `Retrofit`'s `Observable` to receive data or error in singlton and re-subscribe to `BehaviorSubject` in fragment.

```
public class SingltonRetrofitNew
{
    private static RxJavaCallAdapterFactory rxAdapter = RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io());

    private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    private static Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Const.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(rxAdapter)
            .build();

    private static GetModels apiService = retrofit.create(GetModels.class);

    private static BehaviorSubject<ArrayList<Model>> observableModelsList;
    private static Observable<ArrayList<Model>> observable = apiService.getModelsList();
    private static Subscription subscription;

    private SingltonRetrofitNew()
    {
    }

    public static void resetObservable()
    {
        observableModelsList = BehaviorSubject.create();

        if (subscription != null && !subscription.isUnsubscribed())
        {
            subscription.unsubscribe();
        }
        subscription = observable.subscribe(new Subscriber<ArrayList<Model>>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted()
            {
                //do nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e)
            {
                observableModelsList.onError(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(ArrayList<Model> hotels)
            {
                observableModelsList.onNext(hotels);
            }
        });
    }


    public static Observable<ArrayList<Model>> getModelsObservable()
    {
        if (observableModelsList == null)
        {
            resetObservable();
        }
        return observableModelsList;
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
public class FragmentsList extends Fragment
{
    private static final String TAG = FragmentList.class.getSimpleName();
    private Subscription subscription;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ArrayList<Hotel> models = new ArrayList<>();
    private boolean isLoading;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        //init views
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        if (savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            models = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(Const.KEY_MODELS);
            isLoading = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(Const.KEY_IS_LOADING);
        }

        if (models.size() == 0 || isLoading)
        {
            getModelsList();
        }
        //TODO show saved data if is

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (subscription != null && !subscription.isUnsubscribed())
        {
            subscription.unsubscribe();
        }
    }

    private void getModelsList()
    {
        if (subscription != null && !subscription.isUnsubscribed())
        {
            subscription.unsubscribe();
        }
        subscription = SingltonRetrofitNew.getModelsObservable().
                subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).
                observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
                subscribe(new Subscriber<ArrayList<Hotel>>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted()
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onCompleted");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e)
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onError", e);
                        Snackbar.make(recyclerView, R.string.connection_error, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .setAction(R.string.try_again, new View.OnClickListener()
                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v)
                                    {
                                        SingltonRetrofitNew.reset();
                                        getModelsList();
                                    }
                                })
                                .show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(ArrayList<Hotel> newModels)
                    {
                        models.clear();
                        models.addAll(newModels);
                        //TODO show data
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelableArrayList(Const.KEY_MODELS, models);
        outState.putBoolean(Const.KEY_IS_LOADING, isLoading);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me what Const.KEY_MODELS is?

Comment: @S.RLobato, it's just a String constant, you could replace it with any string

Comment: Thanks, I noticed. I would like to adopt your idea, but I am using a List, how can I achieve this using the savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList, which doesn't accepts a List?

Comment: @S.RLobato, you could create an ArrayList from yours List so `new ArrayList<>(yoursList)`. Notice, that content of this list must implement `Parcelable` interface

Comment: @S.RLobato, try `putSerializable()` `getSerializeble()` instead